# How to create new nodes for a binary tree in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a binary search tree and I understand the basic functions that accompany one, but I'm stuck on one thing. In my main function:

```
struct listing
{
    int id;
    char agent[12];
    int price;
    int size; //In square feet
    int numBeds;
    double numBaths;
    int yearBuilt;
    char address[30];
    struct listing *left;
    struct listing *right;
};

struct listing* addListing(struct listing *node, int id, char agent[12], int price, int size, int numBeds, double numBaths, int yearBuilt,
char address[ADD_LENGTH])
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        struct listing *newNode = (struct listing*)malloc(sizeof(struct listing));
        newNode->id = id;
        newNode->agent[12] = agent[12];
        newNode->price = price;
        newNode->size = size;
        newNode->numBeds = numBeds;
        newNode->numBaths = numBaths;
        newNode->yearBuilt = yearBuilt;
        newNode->address[ADD_LENGTH] = address[ADD_LENGTH];
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right = NULL;
        return newNode;
    }

    if(id > node->id)
    {
       node->right = addListing(node->right, id, agent, price, size, numBeds, numBaths, yearBuilt, address);
    }
    else if(id < node->id)
    {
        node->left = addListing(node->left, id, agent, price, size, numBeds, numBaths, yearBuilt, address);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int i;
    struct listing* newNode = NULL;
    newNode = addListing(newNode, 143, "Blaze", 32, 400500, 13, 6.5, 2016, "8802 Reedy Drive");
    struct listing* newNode2 = addListing(newNode, 165, "Target", 78, 502050, 12, 8.0, 2017, "1648 Relish Lane");

    return 0;
}
```

I have this, and I found this implementation online, but I'm not sure exactly what it means. Can someone enlighten me? Thank you.

Comment: You need to post `struct listing` and `addListing()`. We're not telepaths.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was trying to make it so that I didn't need to, but I will. My bad xD

Comment: It's a binary tree, right? So `listing` is a node, and `addListing()` is a function to push something on to the tree.

Comment: It adds a new node with the specified information. The empty tree is considered to have "root" with value `NULL`. `newNode` is initialized to `NULL` and added to the tree, signifying that there was no previous root. The returned root is stored as the new value of `newNode`. It then adds another node to the newly created tree and stores the return value in `newNode2`. Whether `newNode2` is the same as `newNode` or not is up to however `addListing()` works, not that it matters much as long as `NULL` isn't returned.

Comment: Would anything change if I removed the "2" from "newNode2"?

Comment: @Malzahar_Beats_All Well, first of all, it would not compile because you'd be declaring a variable twice. But I think I know what you mean, and it would do the same thing. The only difference would be that you would lose the head of the tree, which was held in `newNode`, because you'd have overwritten it.

Comment: Are you just confused about what the `main()` function does?

Comment: Thing is, I am only testing it now to see if it prints what I want. My only problem is, when the instructor grades my program, they usually have a large test file. I want to know the simplest way of creating the nodes without having to create a new variable each time. Is that possible?

Comment: @Malzahar_Beats_All You only need one node pointer: one as the root of the tree (the first add operation). Any other add operations may or may not return `NULL`. You can handle this with, e.g., `if (tree_add(root, value1, value2, value3, ...) == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "unable to add to tree\n"); tree_burn(root); return EXIT_FAILURE; }`. I recommend looking for a tutorial on binary search trees. [This one is a good introduction](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_bst1.aspx) in my opinion.

Comment: `newNode->agent[12] = agent[12];` --> `strcpy(newNode->agent, agent);` or  `memcpy(newNode->agent, agent, sizeof(newNode->agent));`